# Matlab GUI, radio buttons, plotting

Tags: matlab, radio-button, matlab-guide

I have two radio buttons `radiobutton1`,`radiobutton2` (not in a group) in GUI, each of them plot on the `axes1`a specific function. If I select `radiobutton1` and `radiobutton2` the two functions will be plotted on the `axes1`. If I unselect `radiobutton1` there will be only function of  `radiobutton2` on the `axes1`, the function of `radiobutton1` will not be seen anymore. The same for `radiobutton2`. Or If I unselect two radio buttons nothing will be plotted.

I have defined `if` loop for each radio buttons such as

```
    v = get(hObject,'Value');

if (v == 1)
    axes(handles.axes1);
    plot(sin(x));
    hold on;
else
    cla;
end
```

I tried `cla` to clear `axes1`, but it clears all the plots when one radio button is unselected.

I have written two radio buttons for the sake of simplicity. But I have many of them. So please think the solution for many radio buttons.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to plot both functions and save their handles. Then toggle with the radio buttons the **visibility** of the lines. Try out my example:

```
function myGUI

% Plot two functions immediately and save handles
x   = 1:.1:10;
h.l = plot(x,rem(x,2)-1,'r',x,sin(x),'b');

% Create two radio buttons which share the same '@toggle' callback and index 
% the respective line with the position stored in 'UserData'
h.rb = uicontrol('style','radio','string','redline',...
                 'units','norm','pos',[0.13 0.93 0.1 0.05],...
                 'Value',1, 'callback',@toggle, 'UserData',1);

h.rb = uicontrol('style','radio','string','blueline',...
                 'units','norm','pos',[0.35 0.93 0.1 0.05],...
                 'Value',1,'callback',@toggle,'UserData',2);

h.states = {'off','on'};

    % Toggle visibility
    function toggle(src,event)
        idxLine  = get(src,'UserData');
        idxState = get(src,'Value')+1;
        set(h.l(idxLine),'Visible', h.states{idxState})        
    end
end
```

I initialize everything to visible, but it can be done otherwise:

[image]